# CMake does not properly insert CFBundleVersion and CFBundleShortVersionString to Info.plist

Tags: cmake, info.plist

According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST.html), CMake should use the values of `MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION` and `MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING` target properties to populate `CFBundleVersion` and `CFBundleShortVersionString` in the generated `Info.plist`.

Here is the example of `CMakeLists.txt` I have:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project (foo)

set(SOURCES foo.m)
set(HEADERS foo.h)

add_library(foo
    SHARED
    ${SOURCES}
    ${HEADERS}
)

set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_NAME Foo
    FRAMEWORK TRUE
    FRAMEWORK_VERSION A
    MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER test.foo
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING 1.42.0
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION 1.42.0
    MACOSX_RPATH TRUE
    # "current version" in semantic format in Mach-O binary file
    VERSION 1.42.0
    # "compatibility version" in semantic format in Mach-O binary file
    SOVERSION 1.42.0
    PUBLIC_HEADER "${HEADERS}"
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "dwarf-with-dsym"
)
```

And here is the contents of `Foo.framework/Resources/Info.plist` that CMake generates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>Foo</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>test.foo</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>FMWK</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CSResourcesFileMapped</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So, `CFBundleIdentifier` and `CFBundleExecutable` are properly replaced, but `CFBundleVersion` and `CFBundleShortVersionString` are not. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use another set of options as documented here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_INFO_PLIST.html

that is

```
MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_SHORT_VERSION_STRING
MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_BUNDLE_VERSION
```

because in your case it's not a regular bundle, it's a framework (i.e. library in a bundle)